# Check django permission or operator?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, permissions

For my view, I am checking the permission through the @permission_required decorator but I really wish to check for "either" permission A or permission B. so if user has at least one of two permissions, the view is execute...

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own decorator for this.
Or use `django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test(your_test_func)` to create a custom decorator.

In both cases, have a look at the source code of the `permission_required` decorator in the above module.